# What's the correct way to perform DOM manipulation in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'm using a package called Timeline

https://github.com/VeriteCo/TimelineJS

It works by having a placeholder such as

```
<div id="my-timeline"></div>
```

And then ultimately making a jQuery call to manipulate the div.  Visually I'm seeing the timeline appear on the screen and then disappearing almost straight away.  A similar effect occurs with the following simple example:

```
<div id="my-temp"></div>
```

combined with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-temp').html('HELLO');
});
```

What's the correct way to perform this type of manipulation without having the resultant HTML disappear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you should use [constant regions](http://docs.meteor.com/#constant) to prevent Meteor from re-rendering your div.

```
{{#constant}}
    <div id="my-temp"></div> 
{{/constant}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Handlebars template, don't use jQuery's dom manipulation. If you have to use javascript dom manipulation, make sure to use `Meteor.render()`.

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_render

Also you need to call your timeline creation code inside Template.myTemplate.rendered

http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered

Comment: What if it's a third party library doing the DOM manipulation?  Does that render the library incompatible?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor Render is the right way to go as mentioned by Harry. Here's the link to the new documentation 
http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-onRendered