# Meteor JS: use external script

Tags: javascript, meteor

There are some services (like FB like or AddThis) that provide a snippet of code.
It looks like

```
<div class="service-name" data-something="x"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/service-name.js"></script>
```

OK, cool, so normally you paste it to your HTML and it works. Not with Meteor.

Here's what I see:

- `<script>` inside of template / body **is not loading** -- I don't see it in Resources, something in Meteor is actually preventing browser from recognizing it as a JS file
- it works from `<head>`

Now here are the problems and questions:

1. I don't want loading it from `<head>` -- because of the speed
2. Even if I load it from there -- we have QA and PROD environments. They **must** load this script from different domains (like `service-domain-qa.example` vs. `example.com`)

And surprisingly you **cannot** use template helpers / variables in the `<head>`.

With traditional frameworks it's not a question at all - you can include scripts anywhere and they just load; you can use logic / variables in any part of you *server* templates.

So, how should I do this in Meteor?
Let me repeat:

- I need some external scripts (hosted on 3rd party domain) to be loaded into my app page
- Saving this script into my project's folder is **not an option**
- Script path depends on the environment (we already have the settings system), so the place of the template that renders it should be passed some data from the code

I know the way to achieve this with dynamic script loading from my code (with `LAB.js` or whatever) on Template.created, but this is so much an overkill...

Comment: Meteor 1.2-rc.7 (and perhaps earlier versions) now execute these scripts.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`<script>` tags in body or templates aren't executed by Meteor, they are parsed and then handled by Meteor's templating system. You can't expect a script tag in either of those to just work as it would with a normal HTML page.

The solution is to use Template events (where you could manually append the script tag to the body or something) or load it dynamically like you said. It's not overkill, it's how Meteor works - remember, there is no traditional HTML page or body, there's just the Meteor API, and the Meteor API specifies that in order to load and execute external scripts, you must use the appropriate API methods.

Comment: at the end of the day it's HTML in the browser. it so strange a script tag inserted into the page is not *just working*. what's much stranger - you guys think that's OK :)

Comment: Because there's a good reason - Meteor completely manages the DOM for you, and may possibly reinsert elements or move things around depending on reactivity. So just putting a script in the body and expecting it to work makes no sense; it would get re-executed and mess everything up if the template rerendered. That's why you can just put it in the head, and it will work that way. Or, Meteor offers an alternative as I described in my answer. Up to you to choose from those two options.

Comment: "So just putting a script in the body and expecting it to work makes no sense; it would get re-executed and mess everything up if the template rerendered" — hm, I've heard a legend 'bout `{{#constant}}`

Comment: but anyway, well, I did it like you said "manually append the script tag to the body". still ugly as hell, but works

Comment: *my code* is an external script as clearly stated in the question. currently I do exactly this: manually append script tag to body on template rendered event. and it's awful

Comment: {{#constant}} doesn't seem to work for me. I can see <script> tags in the browser DOM (with or without {{#constant}}) but the page it still doesn't seem to be run. That's weird.

Comment: Oh maybe I see it. Constant is not what I think it is. I was wrapping around my <script> tags. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060173/whats-the-correct-way-to-perform-dom-manipulation-in-meteor

Comment: Is there an example to Template.name.rendered to manually append script tag?

Comment: I don't get why meteor doesn't emit a warning about tags that are not executed.

Comment: The problem is that the content you write in the body tag is not treated as usual. Meteor consider it as a template, not a tag. However I think it should work out of the box to add scripts in a template. The after first time the body templated is rendered, all containing script tags should be extracted and run, so much simpler to test stuff!

Comment: think about it this way: if you load Google Analytics once in the header of a single-page application (SPA) it's not going to fire events when you change routes because those routes don't reload the page in the same way as a traditional web application. SPA are different.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question. Let say you want to use the soundcloud api. `<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script>` Where in meteor do I add that so it gets loaded when my app launches? Putting in Template events means it will injected multiple times. I just want it included once with everything else. How?

Answer (score 25):

My solution is use packages. See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/spiderable for more details.

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "External script"
});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.use(['templating'], 'client');

  api.add_files('external_script.html', 'client');
});



<head><script type="text/javascript" src=""//mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js""></script></head>
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are using IronRouter you can load external scipt using this package:
https://github.com/DerMambo/wait-on-lib

```
Router.map( function () {
  this.route('codeEditor',{
    waitOn: IRLibLoader.load('https://some-external.com/javascript.js')
  });
});
```

Comment: sidenote: this requires the package wait-on-lib (https://atmospherejs.com/manuelschoebel/wait-on-lib)

Answer (score 8):

Why not use jQuery's getscript?

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

You can add a callback function

Comment: This is great, but what can I do to achieve similar functionality on the server side? (With this I get a "$ is not defined" error I'm assuming because jQuery isn't available on the server.

Comment: Adding a heavy external lib for a core functionality is not viable.

Comment: @RuneJeppesen They changed phrasing in docs. It used to have a red warning along the lines of “even though this library is included by the framework, you should opt-in for it, as we might change it”, for Underscore and a few other packages.

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/)  to load the script asynchronously. I use this to load leaflet as and when I need. I'm starting to move over to loading more scripts via yepnope, so that my application renders the bare minimum on initial page load. I place the yepnope stuff inside Template.created.

Comment: Sweet advice! +1 added :)

Comment: yepnope has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Using iframe and the public directory was a hack I used to get script code embedded. In this it was for google adwords code and I did this my main html template:

```
<iframe src="/gads.html?v={{{unique}}}" seamless width="160" height="600"
 scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
 style="margin:0;padding:0;border:none;width:160px;height:600px"></iframe>
```

and then in the public directory put an gads.html file with my google adwords code, like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-54*********";
google_ad_slot = "66******";
google_ad_width = 160;
google_ad_height = 600;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

that worked to get the code on the page, although it's far from ideal (for one thing, I think it violates google's terms of service).

Comment: How does the HTML get the `unique` parameter you pass to it via `<iframe src="/gads.html?v={{{unique}}}">` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using METEOR 1.0. I have put all external SCRIPT tags inside a DIV element right before the   tag in the layout template. Meteor recognizes them without any issue and they are loaded by browser.