# Adding Google Adsense to Meteor Application

Tags: meteor

Tried several methods but still unable to get Google Ad to render. The intention is to responsively place ads based on window width. But I'm unable to place even a single ad.

Here's the most reliable method I can think of:

```
/* templates.html */
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var googletag = googletag || {};
        googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js">       </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        {{> page}}
    </div>
</body>

<template name="page">
    <div class="page_ad"></div>
</template>

/* client.js */
Template.page.rendered = function(){
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        googletag.defineSlot('LEADERBOARD', [728, 90], 'AD-CODE-ID').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.enableServices();
    });

    $('.page_ad').html("<div id='AD-CODE-ID' style='width:728px; height:90px;'>");

    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('AD-CODE-ID')});
};
```

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Do you have any reactive stuff in that page too? Also if you inspect the html with chrome (not view page source as it wont have anything in it) do you see the `<div id='ADD-CODE-ID' st...` any js errors in your webkit inspector/firebug?

Comment: Adsense now offers a (beta) async version that works fine with meteor. 
Put `<script async src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>` on the head, the `ins` block in a template and the script line in the rendered event.

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I do it. **[You can read more about it in this blog post](http://journal.gentlenode.com/meteor-18-how-to-add-google-adsense-to-your-application/).**

```
Template.MyAds.rendered = function() {  
  $.getScript("//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js", function() {
    var ads, adsbygoogle;
    ads = '<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-72414***074839" data-ad-slot="4009***57" data-ad-format="auto"></ins>';
    $('.leaderboard').html(ads);
    return (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  });
};
```

Comment: gentlenode is down? Real pity. The journal was a good resource.

Comment: This was a lifesaver! Exactly what I needed to get ads to load in my SPA.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the iframe solution here; [Meteor JS: use external script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389766/meteor-js-use-external-script)

Check out the information about that method being against TOS; http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/adsense/adsense-basics-and-policies/JP6vrWxFMVg

Comment: Can you complete your answer adding an example?