# Meteor app bootstrap scrollspy error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

Have a Meteor app with Bootstrap (manually inserted in the public/javascript directory). Every time I'm executing the app, I get the following:

```
Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
debug.js:41 TypeError: $(...).scrollspy is not a function
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js?1015953f785c9b76503e2ecb391507dce965f357:365:22), <anonymous>:20:15)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js?1015953f785c9b76503e2ecb391507dce965f357:365:22), <anonymous>:48:3)
    at eval (native)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js?1015953f785c9b76503e2ecb391507dce965f357:365:22
    at Function.jQuery.extend.globalEval (http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js?1015953f785c9b76503e2ecb391507dce965f357:366:7)
    at jQuery.ajaxSetup.converters.text script (http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js?1015953f785c9b76503e2ecb391507dce965f357:9792:11)
    at ajaxConvert (http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js?1015953f785c9b76503e2ecb391507dce965f357:8864:18)
    at done (http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js?1015953f785c9b76503e2ecb391507dce965f357:9285:15)
    at callback (http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js?1015953f785c9b76503e2ecb391507dce965f357:9739:8)
    at Object.send (http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js?1015953f785c9b76503e2ecb391507dce965f357:9745:7)
```

I checked the 'public/javascript/bootstrap.js' file and there is a function 'ScrollSpy(element, options)' so *it is* a function it seems. Hence, no idea what is wrong here...

EDIT:

I'm loading the files in a layout.js file:

```
Template.layout.rendered = function() {
  $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="/frontend/javascript/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>');
  $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="/frontend/javascript/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>');
  $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="/frontend/javascript/jquery.fittext.js"></script>');
  $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="/frontend/javascript/wow.min.js"></script>');
  $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="/frontend/javascript/creative.js"></script>');
}
```

Strange is that I'm not loading the bootstrap javascript, but I'm still getting bootstrap layout and functionality. Loading the minimized bootstrap in the above layout.js results in having no navigation menu (it is there but does not show)

EDIT: Directory structure

```
client
  helpers
  lib
    frontend
       css
templates
  authenticated
  layouts
  public   
lib
public
  frontend
     fonts
     img
     javascript
server
   ...
```

Comment: Public files are not auto loaded into the app. Are you including those scripts anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Public files are not auto-loaded into the app, you need to include them manually. [This Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14389842/759316) provides details on how to include external scripts. Files in the public directory can be accessed using absolute urls: `/javascript/bootstrap.js`.

I recommend just using the Bootstrap package however, you can install it using: `meteor add twbs:bootstrap`. More information about the package can be found on [Atmosphere, the package browsing site for Meteor](https://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap).

Comment: I edited the original question with some more info on the loading of the javascript files. In the use of meteor add twbs:bootstrap I read here (http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-and-twitter-bootstrap---the-right-way) that this was not the right way to do it. Note: i'm integrating a premade bootstrap theme called Creative into my app, which works OK if I don't include Bootstrap js file (but then I have the scrollspy error). If I do load bootstrap.js I have no menu.

Comment: What is the directory structure of your app? Because `/frontend` isn't a path people usually us in their app. Also, I don't see you including the `bootstrap.js` file in that code.

Comment: I added directory structure in the original question. Indeed, am using frontend as I wanted to have a separate layout for front and backend. It works all OK if I don't include the bootstrap.js file, but when I do so I don't have a nav menu.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what your problem is. The bootstrap css is in client/lib/frontend? That would get autoloaded. Bootstrap styles can work fine without the Bootstrap javascript,  but to get scrollspy working, you need to include the bootstrap.js file.

Comment: Indeed, you got the problem. But how come that if I load the bootstrap.js file that my nav menu disappears while it is working if I don't add the bootstrap.js file. I thought js and css don't step on each other's toes normally :-). Any thoughts on why this is?

Comment: That sounds like a different problem then your original question. I would post a new question with your markup and javascript.