# How Can I Run a Bash Script in Meteor JS?

Tags: bash, meteor

I'm working on a little Meteor app and I need to execute some commands to another program, get those results, and then work with those results on the server side. I have located a couple of similar answers like the following but they're not quite what I need:

[Meteor JS: use external script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389766/meteor-js-use-external-script)

---

Example

1. Client-side displays information about files which are stored on a
   3rd party service
2. When client requests a file, server calls the other program (a bash
   script in this case) to retrieve the file
3. Once retrieved, the file is available for the client to download

   ---

I have #1 and #3 working, minus some additional testing I will integrate once I figure out how to do #2. I guess what I probably need is a way for Meteor to execute arbitrary code which resides on the server?

Comment: with child process - https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process

Comment: @YOU Thanks, checking it out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [blog post](https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2015/02/26/meteor-run-shell-command-at-server-side/) shows how to run shell commands in Meteor using `fibers` package from NPM.

**To install fibers:**

```
npm -g install fibers
```

**To run your bash code:**

```
// Load future from fibers
var Future = Npm.require("fibers/future");
// Load exec
var exec = Npm.require("child_process").exec;

// Server methods
Meteor.methods({
    runCode: function () {

        // This method call won't return immediately, it will wait for the
        // asynchronous code to finish, so we call unblock to allow this client
        // to queue other method calls (see Meteor docs)

        this.unblock();
        var future=new Future();
        var command="pwd";
        exec(command,function(error,stdout,stderr) {
            if(error) {
                console.log(error);
                throw new Meteor.Error(500,command+" failed");
            }
            future.return(stdout.toString());
        });
        return future.wait();
    }
});
```

You can also try out some of the AtmosphereJS packages for this, like [jchristman:exec](https://atmospherejs.com/jchristman/exec).

Comment: Thanks! This looks good too. Going to do some experimentation and will come back and vote the best answer if it's here :)

Comment: Hi @nosforever, were you able to get the bash script running?

Comment: Hi @Nivedit. I wasn't able to previously, but you convinced me to give it another shot. I didn't previously see the website you listed at the top of your post, and that made it exceptionally clear what was needed. Thank you!

Comment: Great @nosforever! :) I see that you are new to StackOverflow. If you feel like an answer helped you, please consider upvoting it and also marking it as accepted answer.