# Datatables not working with Meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor, datatables

I'm trying to include a Datatable in a Meteor app, but getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function(…)
```

Inside my `client/` folder, in the `main.html` file, I have this minimal code:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="tableId"></table>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#tableId').DataTable();
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

[Here's a demo](https://github.com/anubhav756/meteor-datatable) of my problem

**PS** - when I run the HTML file itself (without Meteor), I don't get this error. So, is it something wrong between Datatable and Meteor, or am I missing something here?

### Update

It seems that adding [this meteor package](https://github.com/ksrv/datatables/) solves the problem.

Great! But wait a minute, this package just adds a single library file, namely, [jquery.dataTables.min.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ksrv/datatables/master/jquery.dataTables.min.js), **the same file that I have been adding this whole time**!

```
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

I guess, now the question is, what magic does this package do, while injecting the js file?

Comment: everything looks good for me... can you check if there are other `jquery` files or datatables inculded ...

Comment: @RajshekarReddy I've checked that on the [website](https://datatables.net/manual/installation). PS - it works fine when running without meteor (by double clicking on the HTML file)

Comment: are you injecting DataTable correctly?

Comment: @darryn.ten I'm doing it according to the docs [here](https://datatables.net/manual/installation), ie. add jQuery, datatable js and css, and initialize. It's correct right?

Comment: meteor has its own special way of injecting dependencies

Comment: Any reason you're not using the [npm package](https://datatables.net/download/npm#NPM-package-installation) or [meteor packages](https://atmospherejs.com/packages/DataTable%20)?

Comment: @Jeremiah please see the update to my question. Thanks :)

Comment: @darryn.ten Yes, but what is this _"special way"_? Please see the updated question. Thanks :)

Comment: You can read more about them in the [meteor guide](https://guide.meteor.com), under [atmosphere packages](https://guide.meteor.com/using-atmosphere-packages.html) and [npm packages](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html)

Comment: @Anubhav Dhawan Here's a good explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/14389842/1689286

Comment: @Jeremiah Thanks. Finally somebody put this thing in words

Comment: @Jeremiah you can post this as an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is that you do not have enough information either in the table definition or the datatable function.  I made one change and it started working.

```
<table id="tableId"><thead><tr><th>d</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody><tfoot></tfoot></table>
```

you have to give at least one column

Comment: Have you added datatable files via `<script>` and `<link>` tags, or via meteor packages? Also, you are serving HTML via meteor server right?

Comment: I took your code, main.html, and made the change and it worked after that.

Comment: Ok, but are you serving the html via meteor server, or just double clicking _main.html_ file? Because yes, the latter case works for me too, but I am trying to do this in a Meteor app you see :)

Comment: do you have a main js? I don't see it in your meteor stuff

Comment: Meteor.startup(function() {
        $('#tableId').DataTable();
});  ?

Comment: No luck. Nice idea btw

Comment: did you try it without shortcut notation, ie: Meteor.startup(function() { jQuery('#tableId').DataTable(); });   ?   http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: `jQuery(...).DataTable is not a function(…)`. Sorry no luck. I think, after all, it's a meteor thing not to inject scripts using `<script>`. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
meteor add menway:jquery-datatables
```