# Accessing meteor settings from a <script> in a html <head>

Tags: javascript, html, json, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to get one-signal to manage web push notifications in a meteor.js application. It is required that I set the below code in the head, based on [Onesignal documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-typical-setup) (step 7). so I have placed it in a layout.html.

This works when the onesignal app ID is hard coded in, however I need to pull this key from settings.json. Simply replacing the value with Meteor.settings.public.oneSignalAppId does not seem to work and spacebars are not an option either. I would be happy to move the code if possible however I have had no luck with what I have tried ([another question with some things ive tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389766/meteor-js-use-external-script)).

```
      <script>
   var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
   OneSignal.push(["init",{
     appId: "valueFromSettings",
   }]);
  </script>
```

Comment: Can you show use where and how the data from `settings.json` is loaded on the page? I guess it's _after_ this `script` tag and that's a problem.

Comment: The data from settings is loaded on server startup, it is the default location for this information in meteor. As far as I understand public settings are accessible automatically once the file is loaded. The only thing I cant change is the fact this key is stored here, hopefully this link explains it better. https://blog.meteor.com/the-meteor-chef-making-use-of-settings-json-3ed5be2d0bad

Comment: Is it really required to run inside the `head` or can it wait until the app has initially been loaded?

Comment: I havent been able to run the code successfully any other location ive tried, but if it would just run for me in a template I should be able to access settings from there.